# Why are quantum channels described by linear maps?

Tags: quantum-operation

Why should the [quantum channels](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_channel) be described by *linear* maps?

Comment: [This paper](https://journals.aps.org/pr/abstract/10.1103/PhysRev.121.920) might be helpful, the available pdf is in [this link](https://web2.ph.utexas.edu/~gsudama/pub/1961_010.pdf). Mind that the B-map in the paper is exactly the choi operator.

Answer (score 8):

More precisely, they are described by *affine* maps. This is also not special to quantum mechanics, but rather a more general fact in physical theories (keyword: *generalized probabilistic theory*). Let me elaborate.

Suppose you can prepare two states $s_1$ and $s_2$ of a physical system, then it is always possible to prepare a probabilistic mixture of those. Simply throw a (biased) coin (say head has probability $p$) and prepare state $s_1$ when it shows head and $s_2$ when it's tail.

Mathematically, this means that it is always meaningful to consider *convex combinations* of states, i.e.
$$
 s = p s_1 + (1-p) s_2,
$$
describes another valid state.
This means that the set of physical states has a natural *convex structure* associated.
For instance, states of a classical system are probability measures on phase space, while states of a quantum system are described by density matrices. Both are convex sets.

Now, any physical dynamics should preserve state space, in particular they should preserve *convex combinations*, i.e. we require that the physical mapping obeys
$$
\Phi ( p s_1 + (1-p) s_2) = p \Phi(s_1) + (1-p) \Phi(s_2).
$$
Such a map is called *affine*.

If we embed a convex set into a vector space, these maps are essentially given by linear maps on this vector space (actually *affine transformations*).
For quantum states, we embed state space into the set of complex matrices, thus quantum channels are given by linear maps on complex matrices (with additional constraints, of course).